# How to find last non-empty index in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

I am using an input file to populate my array with different strings. how do I check up to where the array is filled? I initialize the size of my array to 30000, but how do I check up to which index it contains a string?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit to provide examples of your code. How did you create your array?

Comment: Use `int initialCapacity = 1000; List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(initialCapacity);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Low-level approach: while populating the array, maintain a `count` variable, adding 1 to it on every element you insert into the array.

Professional approach: instead of an array, use a `java.util.List`, e.g. a `java.util.ArrayList`. List instances do the counting for you (and by the way, don't waste 25000 empty elements if your file only contains 5000).

Comment: Not to forget the case of 25001 elements. Instead of count, use `list.size()` and usage would be nice: list.add("good")` and  `list.get(i)`